# Got timeout reading communication packets in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql

In our application we are using **MySQL 5.6** and we are getting following warning message randomly:

```
[Warning] Aborted connection 154246 to db: 'xxxxx' user: 'xxxxx' host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (Got timeout reading communication packets)<br/>
[Warning] Aborted connection 154228 to db: 'xxxxx' user: 'xxxxx' host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

We have done following changes to avoid this, but issue still persist:

```
net_read_timeout = 60
connect_timeout = 30
```

Please let us know your suggestions.

Comment: I have had this on occasion, for our systems I found reducing the table_open_cache variable reduced (but did not entirely remove) the occurrences. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Giles..but it is not helping

Comment: Sorry it didn`t help, I found that tip just by googling "got timeout reading communication packets" - you could give that a try if you have not already.